# Determine if coordinates is within bounding box

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, geometry, leaflet

I need to create a function that, given `a`, `b` and `c` returns a boolean indicating if `c` is within `a` and `b`.

All variables have the following type:

```
type Coordinate = {
  lat: number;
  lon: number;
};
```

I've came up with a solution that initially I though was correctly, but after testing with Google Maps, I find out it's wrong.

The function:

```
function inBoundingBox(
  bottomLeft: Coordinate,
  topRight: Coordinate,
  point: Coordinate
) {
  let isLongInRange: boolean;
  if (topRight.lon < bottomLeft.lon) {
    isLongInRange = point.lon >= bottomLeft.lon || point.lon <= topRight.lon;
  } else {
    isLongInRange = point.lon >= bottomLeft.lon && point.lon <= topRight.lon;
  }
  return (
    point.lat >= bottomLeft.lat && point.lat <= topRight.lat && isLongInRange
  );
}
```

One example that should work:

```
const topRight: Coordinate = {
  lat: -23.5273,
  lon: -46.833881
};

const bottomLeft: Coordinate = {
  lat: -23.537519,
  lon: -46.840019
};

const point = {
  lat: -23.52785,
  lon: -46.840545
};

const result = inBoundingBox(bottomLeft, topRight, point);
console.log(result) // false, where should be true.
```

And a visual representation is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYHva.png).

I need help to find out where exactly the code is wrong, and how to fix it.

I also tried to use Leaflet to see if it works, but the result is the same:

```
function leafletContains(bottomLeft, topRight, pos) {
  var bounds = new L.LatLngBounds(
    new L.LatLng(bottomLeft.lat, bottomLeft.lon),
    new L.LatLng(topRight.lat, topRight.lon)
  );
  return bounds.contains(new L.LatLng(pos.lat, pos.lon));
}

leafLetContains({ lat: -23.537519, lon: -46.840019 }, { lat: -23.5273, lon: -46.833881 }, { lat: -23.527811, lon: -46.840201 }) // false, where should be true.
```

Comment: This should be a relatively straightforward math problem. Check to see if the given `lat` is between the topRight and bottomLeft `lat`s, and the same for `lon`. But have you considered the case where the coordinates are near the equator, or one of the meridians? For example, at the antimeridian it switches from 180 degress on the west side to -180 degrees on the east side.

Comment: You could look into using or re-implementing something like this: https://github.com/tparkin/Google-Maps-Point-in-Polygon

Comment: I have, the function it's to supposed to do all of that, and I can't use Google Maps client SDK because I'm calculating this with Node :/.

Comment: In the example you posted the point is *outside* of the box, not inside. The longitude is the culprit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A bounding box test must check the four sides of the box.

A box in the surface of a sphere is not a rectangle, so it's hard to work with x,y coordinates. But with "polar" coordinates (lat, lon) it's a lot easy:

I'm not a javascript coder, so forgive my mistakes in this code:

```
function inBoundingBox(
  bottomLeft: Coordinate,
  topRight: Coordinate,
  point: Coordinate
) {
  let isLongInRange: boolean;
  let isLatiInRange: boolean;
  isLongInRange = point.lon >= bottomLeft.lon && point.lon <= topRight.lon;
  isLatiInRange = point.lat >= bottomLeft.lat && point.lat <= topRight.lat;
  return ( isLongInRange && isLatiInRange );
}
```

assuming `bottomLeft.lon < topRight.lon` and `bottomLeft.lat < topRight.lat`

Comment: It turns out my code was working. I was using open maps to translate human-readable addresses to coordinates and they were returning wrong coordinates lol.

Comment: @Mr920X I think your code works for some cases, fails for others.

Comment: Can you give me one such example?

Comment: @Mr920X Example: tLon=50, bLon=70, pointLon= 30. (notice the wrogly swapped botton/top) Is clearly outside, but the condition `...|| point.lon <= topRight.lon` is true.

Comment: what about cases where the coordinates are near the equator, or one of the meridians? Will your solution handle them correctly? I'm not sure.

Comment: If the criteria followed by some API is special, then you need a special handling too. For example two near latitudes 10 & 350. and you want the 20º width and not the 240º one.

Answer (score 1):

this line is wrong

```
else {
  isLongInRange = point.lon >= bottomLeft.lon && point.lon <= topRight.lon;
}
```

Has to be `||` instead of `&&` and one of the following: switch around
the `>=` and `<=` or switch palces of `bottomLeft.lon` and `topRight.lon`

```
else {
  isLongInRange = point.lon <= bottomLeft.lon || point.lon >= topRight.lon;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure? Counter example: bLon=50, TLon=70, pointLon= 30

Answer (score 0):

One comment mentioned the edge case of the bounding box crossing the equator, and also date lines, where latitude and/or longitude coordinates change sign. My solution will "move" the bounding box off of those lines and also move the point as well. At this point in the problem, it is not a matter of is the point over a particular location, but is it within the box.

For example, if the box is N "units" (radians or DMS) below the equator, then "move" the box up by N units and also the point, then do the math.

And, yes, I know that moving a bounding box on the surface of a sphere changes its physical size, but that is not the point at this time. The question is: Is BB-LL-lat < Point-lat < BB-UR-lat? And similar for longitude. Adjusting the coordinate system does not affect the math relationship, despite changes in physical dimension when projected on to the Earth. The question is NOT "what is the distance?", it IS "Is the point between the lines?"